# onBackPressed sometimes or always called automaticaly when starting activity

Tags: android, keyevent, onbackpressed

i have problem with my app in some devices (HUAWEI P10 Lite, rockchip A95XR3). Maybe more in future.

According to users, when opening the Video Player Activity, the app immediately crashes.

I think, when they open the Video Player Activity, they quickly press the back button when Activity is not ready. So I tried to use my Oppo Realme 5Pro device and then tried to hit the back button with lightning speed, but it didn't crash (I tried several times). And I also tried running it on the emulator according to the Android version with problems 8.0.0 and 9.

Stack Trace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void c.d.b.a.t0.b()' on a null object reference
       at com.**cencored**.C_Video_Player.ReleasePlayer(Act_Video_Player.java:163)
       at com.**cencored**.C_Video_Player.onBackPressed(Act_Video_Player.java:405)
       at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:3161)
       at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2779)
       at androidx.core.view.KeyEventDispatcher.activitySuperDispatchKeyEventPre28(KeyEventDispatcher.java:137)
       at androidx.core.view.KeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEventDispatcher.java:87)
       at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:133)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:558)
       at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2814)
       at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:415)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5191)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5063)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4581)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4634)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4600)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4727)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4608)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4784)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4581)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4634)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4600)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4608)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4581)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4634)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4600)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4760)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4921)
       at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2599)
       at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:2160)
       at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:2151)
       at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2574)
       at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:379)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

If I see Stack Trace through Firebase Crashlytics, it looks like `onBackPressed` has been called, but according to the user they don't press the back button.

Below this is part of the code that is related to the problem.

```
private void ReleasePlayer() {
        exoPlayer.release(); //Line 163
        isVideoPrepared ="no";
        TextError.setVisibility(GONE);
        TextReconnecting.setVisibility(GONE);
        TextTryCount.setVisibility(GONE);
    }

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        exoPlayerView.setVisibility(GONE);
        forInfo.setVisibility(GONE);
        forAds.setVisibility(GONE);
        forControl.setVisibility(GONE);
        ReleasePlayer(); //Line 405
        finish();
   }
```

On the stack trace above also not mentioned `onCreate`, so of course the `exoplayer` has not been initialized yet.

The real question is, what are the problems with the above devices? or maybe in my code?

Comment: Maybe your exoPlayer was not or never instantiated properly... how was it assigned?

Comment: If so, why on most devices my app runs normally and on my device too even on the emulator. So I don't think that's the cause. What confused me most was why `onBackPressed` was called and who called? I did not call `onBackPressed` at any event in the video player activity. thanks for your fast response.

Comment: You're getting NullPointerException when you're trying to invoke something on a null object, so it's pretty clear that exoPlayer was null when back press happened. I wonder if the variable was assigned asynchronously, or outside of activity lifecycle, or set to null at some stage later.